# How to find OpenVPN is installed or not

Tags: ios, vpn

I searched for **OpenURL** scheme to find OpenVPN is installed or not.
so far no luck.
is there any other way I can verify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenVPN Connect 1.0.6 and higher installs the *openvpn://* URL scheme and can be detected with the following code:

```
BOOL installed = [application canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"openvpn://"]];
```

[Reference](https://docs.openvpn.net/docs/openvpn-connect/openvpn-connect-ios-faq.html)

Comment: exactly what I was looking for.. thanks, reference is also helpful

Answer (score 1):

In iOS < 9 you can easily check wether an Application is installed or not, in case you know the exact URL scheme.

For this you could use the functions `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:yourURL]` and `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:yourURL]`. This functions were used by different Applications to check which Apps are installed to provide custom Ads.

With the Update to iOS 9 this functionality is limited. "Starting on iOS 9, apps will have to declare what URL schemes they would like to be able to check for and open in the configuration files of the app as it is submitted to Apple."(Awkward Hare - [Quick Take on iOS 9 URL Scheme Changes](http://awkwardhare.com/post/121196006730/quick-take-on-ios-9-url-scheme-changes))

Edit: URL scheme provided by: Durai Amuthan.H

Best Regards